# PFFile AS UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimage

I have a parse backend, and I am putting at the rows into an array in swift, and then displaying them in a tableview. All the labels are fine and I am having trouble with an Image column (PFFile).

Here is my code to retrieve the data and place into an array

```
  var GetAllEvents : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Types_")
        GetAllEvents.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) ->Void in

            if (error == nil) {
                for object in objects {
                    self.EventData.addObject(object)
                    println(object)


                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

Then I retrieve the content in cellforindexpath , like this :

```
cell.EventTitle.text = (event.objectForKey("Title") as String!)
cell.EventType.text = (event.objectForKey("TypeOfVenue_") as String!)
```

I am having trouble with the image , I have written this  :

cell.TypeImage.image = (event.objectForKey("TyoeImage") as PFFile)

but as UIImage is not a PFFile, it shows an error. Whats the best way to display this image ?

thanks

Comment: Jason, see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595220/downloading-pffile-image-from-parse-append-it-to-array-and-fill-uiimageview-wi/27596932#27596932

Comment: Hi there, yes I have already looked at your answer but I done want to download twice, as its a waste!

Comment: What do you mean download twice

Comment: well I used [anyobject] to download all the strings and files, then I cast them AS String and I thought id be able to case the file as NSData. without doing another download block. but with your idea I have a download block for strings and then one for PFFiles.

Comment: You can use the same download block. I was simply pointing you to the right direction for the correct syntax of downloading images from parse

Comment: Objectforkey is wrong, especially your syntax.  PFFiles aren't objects and images are especially data. So just use the link or any other link it doesn't have to be mine. I was just trying to guide you through the correct syntax and don't want to answer on a duplicated question.