# casting a PFFile as NSData from Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimage

I have an class in Parse which has been put into an array, like this :

```
 // PFQuery to get all Events
        var GetAllEvents : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Types_")
        GetAllEvents.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) ->Void in

            if (error == nil) {
                for object in objects {
                    self.EventData.addObject(object)
                    println(object)


                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            }else
            {
                println("Error \(error)")
            }
        }
```

I am trying to put the results into a tableview, and this is fine with the strings , but with the image I am really struggling.

```
 cell.EventTitle.text = (event.objectForKey("Title") as String!)
        cell.EventType.text = (event.objectForKey("TypeOfVenue_") as String!)

        var image = UIImage(data: (event.objectForKey("TypeImage"))! as NSData)
```

So when i try and create  an variable for the image - it just crashes, any ideas ?

Comment: See my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595220/downloading-pffile-image-from-parse-append-it-to-array-and-fill-uiimageview-wi/27596932#27596932

Answer (score 3):

`PFFile` can't be casted to `NSData`, what you need to do is to use it method `getData` to retrieve `NSData`:

```
let file = event["TypeImage"]
file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
   if let data = data where error == nil{
   var image = UIImage(data: data)
}
})
```